# I can't graph lines on my TI-84 Plus

Tags: calculator

On my TI 84 Plus CE, I have $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ filled with equations, both under Plot 1. When I select Plot 1 and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to select it to graph, the plot doesn't show up under <kbd>graph</kbd>. Instead, I see a scatter plot based off of my data in $L_1$ and $L_2$. I go to <kbd>2nd</kbd><kbd>stat plot</kbd> and turn off Plot 1, but then Plot 1 under <kbd>y=</kbd> is also deselected.

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Note: This should be on-topic, because in the Help Center, it says math software questions are on topic.

Comment: Actually, never mind, the problem fixed itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what happened, but I deleted the values in $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ for the umpteenth time, and suddenly everything worked fine.

Comment: Please accept your answer to keep the question from being recycled into the Unanswered queue. Cheers! :)

Comment: Will do. It's been almost 3 years since I've seen this post lol, thanks for the reminder